# Can i use ibooks interface within my application?

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I want to show the available iBooks in my application. I want to show these in the same style as the iBooks interface.

Can I use Apple's iBooks interface for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant make same view (matter of copy right) but you can open your books in iBooks.
se this [link](http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks) it helps you.

Comment: Why would that link help the asker?

Comment: @nil That links open pdf or eBooks in iBook app from your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to do this.
If you plan on recreating the interface, keep in mind that your app may be rejected if your interface is too similar.